# UIScrollView inside another view not scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

So I've seen other SO questions but I can't really figure out mine

I know my UIScrollView code works because I tested it in a regular UIViewController so I don't think contentSize is the problem, but when I place the same code inside a UICollectionReusableView it doesn't scroll anymore

[image]

```
-Working in UIViewController
    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize: CGSize(width:100.0,height:50.0), buttonCount: 10)

      let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
      scrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
      scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true

      self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
      scrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)

   }

-Not working in UICollectionReusableView

 override init(frame: CGRect) { 
    super.init(frame: frame)

    //Add category scroll view 
    let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize: CGSize(width:100.0,height:50.0), buttonCount: 10)

    let scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
    scrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size

    scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true

    self.addSubview(scrollView) //Only changes self.view to self
    scrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)


 }
```

Comment: is scrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true ?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I added the line but it's still not working

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never...I had the same problem, so maybe this is why;

I wanted to put a `UIScrollView` inside a `UICollectionReusableView` but by accident I had created my custom class as;

```
class CustomCellHeader: UICollectionViewCell {


}
```

instead of;

```
class CustomCellHeader: UICollectionReusableView {


}
```

Once I changed that, the `UIScrollView` within my header cell came to life!